# SVG gets pixelated on Chromium

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend, chromium

Our logo svg is getting pixelated only on Chromium based browsers.
I have seen the other questions and answers with similar issues but that didn't work out.

Any suggestion how to workaround this? I have also filled a bug in Chromium.
Example can be seen here https://cd082856.mirrord-dev.pages.dev/
Attaching screenshots.
[image: Chromium]
[image: Firefoxiuim]

Stuff we've tried:

- 2x/4x svg then resizing.
- using css `transform`

Comment: SVG doesn't look pixelated on my screen (using Chrome)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: My operating system is Windows 10